# Tkinter remove widget instead of just making invisible

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, tk-toolkit

So im just starting out with tkinter, and a big problem im having is removing a widget instead of just making it invisible with grid_forget. Is it possible to do this as currently when i later add more widgets after removing the first, the first is still taking up space above  the second, despite using the same column and rows.

Comment: If you use `grid_forget`, the widget will not take up any space. That's the whole purpose of `grid_forget` -- remove the widget so it doesn't take up any space.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [destroy](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.destroy-method) method:

```
the_widget.destroy()
```